# Procedure SQL Serve c/ ASP

Tags: sql, asp, procedure

boa tarde!
Tenho essa procedure básica no SQL Server, que me traz o percentual de despesa:

```
DECLARE 
    @totalDespesas       FLOAT
    ,@totalDespesasAcomp FLOAT
    ,@resultado          FLOAT  

    SET @totalDespesas      = (SELECT SUM(valorReal) FROM dbo.contasRatear)
    SET @totalDespesasAcomp = (SELECT SUM(valorReal) FROM dbo.contasRatear WHERE acompanhar = 'SIM')
    SET @resultado          = ROUND(((@totalDespesasAcomp / @totalDespesas) * 100),2)

SELECT @resultado as totalperc
```

Ao receber o valor de resultado no ASP, aparece erro:
"O_item_não_pode_ser_encontrado_na_coleção_correspondente_ao_nome_ou_ao_ordinal_solicitado."

ASP/HTML:

```
                                <%
                                    sql = "EXEC despesasRatearBuscaPercentualDespesas;"
                                    set bd = Conn.execute(sql)
                                %>
                                <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center" id="" class=""><%=bd("totalperc")%>%</th>
```

Conseguem me ajudar?  Obrigado :)

Comment: Me parece que não está encontrando alguma coluna que vc colocou na procedure.

Comment: Obrigado, mas a coluna é:  'totalperc'...

Comment: A conexão está aberta?

Comment: Sim conexão aberta.

Comment: Qualquer outra procedure funciona normalmente. Recupera os "fields"... Acredito que o problema esteja nesta minha procedure...

Answer (score 0):

O que pode estar ocorrendo é que a procedure pode não estar retornando o resultado. Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```html
<%
sql = "EXEC despesasRatearBuscaPercentualDespesas"
set bd = Conn.execute(sql)
if not bd.eof then
%>
<th colspan="1" style="text-align:center" id="" class=""><%=bd.fields("totalperc")%>%</th>
<%
else
response.write("Não retornou informações")
end if
%>
```

Comment: Dando erro na linha do IF:  "Operação_não_permitida_quando_o_objeto_está_fechado. "